# How to Validate a SecurityToken XML String issued by LocalSTS

Tags: visual-studio-2012, wif, saml

Can someone point me to an example that validates tokens issued by the LocalSTS (The STS provider that comes with Identity and Access Tool for VS 2012)

thanks,